# Как убрать возможность хождения сайтов на сервере по https, когда им не установлен сертификат?

Tags: http, https, сертификат

Имеется сервер, на нем у меня лежит около 10 сайтов. На один из них установлен сертификат, привязанный к домену. Установлен вроде как положено. Другие 9 штук не защищены. Если попробовать зайти на любой другой сайт на сервере по протоколу https, то протокол отображается зачеркнутым и открывается тот сайт, на который установлен сертификат. То есть если любому сайту приписать протокол https, то открывается тот, защищенный. Причем имя домена именно то, которое и должно быть. Те, у которых в robots.txt стоит disallowed: / еще и индексируются поисковиками из-за этого.

Можно конечно в htaccess прописать редиректы с https на http, но хочется найти более грамотное решение.
Сертификат устанавливал через Isp manager 5. Сервер на ubuntu 16.04. Apache.

Конфиг сайта, который ходит по https

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
        ServerName site.ru
        DocumentRoot /path/to/site.ru/frontend/web
        ServerAdmin user
        AddDefaultCharset off
        AssignUserID user
        CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/123.access.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/123.error.log
        <FilesMatch "\.ph(p[3-5]?|tml)$">
            SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
        </FilesMatch>
        <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
            SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
        </FilesMatch>
        <IfModule php5_module>
            php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f 123@user.ru"
            php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/../data/mod-tmp"
            php_admin_value session.save_path "/../data/mod-tmp"
            php_admin_value open_basedir "/../data:."
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule php7_module>
            php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f 123"
            php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/.../mod-tmp"
            php_admin_value session.save_path "/.../data/mod-tmp"
            php_admin_value open_basedir "/.../data:."
        </IfModule>
        ServerAlias www.site.ru
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    </VirtualHost>
    <Directory /path/to/site.ru/frontend/web>
        Options +Includes -ExecCGI
        <IfModule php5_module>
            php_admin_flag engine on
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule php7_module>
            php_admin_flag engine on
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    <Directory /path/to/site.ru/frontend/web>
        <IfModule php5_module>
            php_admin_flag engine on
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule php7_module>
            php_admin_flag engine on
        </IfModule>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
    </Directory>
    <VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
        ServerName site.ru
        DocumentRoot /path/to/site.ru/web
        ServerAdmin 123
        AddDefaultCharset off
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "/var/www/httpd-cert/user/site.ru.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/www/httpd-cert/user/site.ru.key"
        SSLHonorCipherOrder on
        SSLProtocol +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
        SSLCipherSuite EECDH:+AES256:-3DES:RSA+AES:!NULL:!RC4
        <IfModule headers_module>
            Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; preload"
        </IfModule>
        AssignUserID user user
        CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/site.ru.access.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/site.ru.error.log
        <FilesMatch "\.ph(p[3-5]?|tml)$">
            SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
        </FilesMatch>
        <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
            SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
        </FilesMatch>
        <IfModule php5_module>
            php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f 123@site.com"
            php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/user/data/mod-tmp"
            php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/user/data/mod-tmp"
            php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/user/data:."
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule php7_module>
            php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f 123@site.com"
            php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/user/data/mod-tmp"
            php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/user/data/mod-tmp"
            php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/user/data:."
        </IfModule>
        ServerAlias www.site.ru
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    </VirtualHost>
    <Directory /path/to/site.ru/frontend/web>
        Options +Includes -ExecCGI
        <IfModule php5_module>
            php_admin_flag engine on
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule php7_module>
            php_admin_flag engine on
        </IfModule>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
    </Directory>
```

Конфиг одного из сайтов, который не ходит по https

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName site2.ru
    DocumentRoot /path/to/site2/frontend/web
    ServerAdmin webmaster@site2.ru
    AddDefaultCharset off
    AssignUserID user user
    CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/site2.ru.access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/site2.ru.error.log
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p[3-5]?|tml)$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    <IfModule php5_module>
        php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@site2.ru"
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/../data/mod-tmp"
        php_admin_value session.save_path "/../data/mod-tmp"
        php_admin_value open_basedir "/../data:."
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule php7_module>
        php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@site2.ru"
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/../data/mod-tmp"
        php_admin_value session.save_path "/../data/mod-tmp"
        php_admin_value open_basedir "/../data:."
    </IfModule>
    ServerAlias www.site.ru
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /path/to/site2/frontend/web>
    Options +Includes +ExecCGI
    <IfModule php5_module>
        php_admin_flag engine on
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule php7_module>
        php_admin_flag engine on
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
<Directory /path/to/site2/frontend/web>
    Options +Includes -ExecCGI
    <IfModule php5_module>
        php_admin_flag engine on
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule php7_module>
        php_admin_flag engine on
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: У вас неправильно настроен веб-сервер. Конкретно, вы используете виртуальные хосты, и для одного, с рабочим https - убрать "default server", вписав конкретный сервер. Что у вас, голый Апач? Или Nginx, или все вместе? Приложите конфиги.

Comment: У меня стоит апач. Конфиги виртуальных хостов расположены по адресу /etc/apache2/vhosts/user/ Для каждого сайта - свой конфиг. Конфиг основного с https приложил

Comment: Вы точно правильно заменили реальные названия на site.ru и site2.ru? Смущает строчка в `Конфиг одного из сайтов, который не ходит по https` `<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>`, `ServerAlias www.site.ru`. Но дело не в ней. Поищите в конфигах `<VirtualHost _default_:443>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

редиректы не спасут тут, неделю назад сам мучался с этим вопрос, правда я решил купить сертификат в итоге. Но для вашей проблемы - нужно сделать бесплатные сертификаты. тк если вы делаете редиректы, то браузер сначала ругается - потом редиректит, то есть толку 0.

Если нужно - [вот инструкция](https://flops.ru/kb/knowledge-base/polutchenie-u-ustanovka-sertifikata-ot-startssl/)

Comment: к слову, гугл считает сайты без сертификата зашкварными, так что сертификат всегда пригодится, да и редирект - это нормально, я лично у себя делаю редиректы так, чтобы в итоге был 1 сайт на https без www чтобы не плодить копии для поисковика